# How to draw dynamic curved line in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview, curve

I have a byte buffer in my Android application,consider it as a vector.The data in the buffer is changed dynamically(There is a separate thread to update the buffer).I want to draw these data dynamically.

Every data represents a point's Y coordinate in the View,connect the consecutive points to form a curve.As the buffer is updated periodically,the curve looks like moving forward smoothly.

Firstly,I implement this by drawing lines in the View's onDraw(Canvas canvas) method,but it is very ineffective.When calling invalidate method is too frequently, the CPU consume is very heavy.

So I change to use the SurfaceView, draw the dynamic curve in the separate thread, but It is still not satisfactory.

I want to know whether there is any good methods to achieve this.Whether is OpenGL ES a choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenGL ES 1.0 you can use `glDrawArrays` in `GL_LINES` mode. It will do exactly what the `Canvas` is doing with your data, but considerably faster